# What video players do you recommend?

Tags: video, software-recommendation, video-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Media Players Are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there)

What video players do you recommend for ubuntu. Is there any video player that supports good playback of 720p videos in oldish hardware?