# Watching a DVD?

Tags: dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-dvd-movies)

I tried to watch a dvd on ubuntu 10.10 but with no success. I went to medibuntu to check that I have all the required repositaries. Everything was up to date. So what's wrong?

Comment: I think it's a defective dvd because now I tried another one and it worked. When I opened movie player or vlc it just opened for a second and it closed again.

Comment: Have you installed libdvdcss?

Comment: yes I checked all the steps with Medibuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu).

Comment: did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the VLC player (available from Ubuntu Software Center). In my opinion VLC has the most complete set of codecs.

Best wishes,
Vincenzo

Comment: I did use the VLC but had the same result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ran to get DVDs working correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I don't know for certain if the first 2 are necessary for VLC, but I was having problems viewing a DVD until I installed the infamous dvdread/dvd-css.

Comment: libdvdread4 is already installed, and VLC too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I installed VLC but in addition I also had to install
libdvdcss. Now I can play any dvd I want using VLC.

Answer (score 0):

From you comments, I'd say the solution is to use a non-defective DVD. Is there a way you could get ahold of a different copy of the same DVD?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Yes that would be the ideal solution to verify if the one I have is defective or not.