# How to play DVDs after installing the recommended libraries?

Tags: dvd

There are couple of similar topics [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17942/watching-a-dvd) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-dvd-movies), but the gist of the answers is to do what's stated in the documentation.

These are the commands I've already run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

sudo apt-get install libdvdread4

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2

sudo apt-get install w64codecs

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

and probably some other codecs and whatnot that I can't remember at the moment.

I've tried three different DVDs on both VLC and MoviePlayer. VLC gives the error "VLC cannot set the DVD's title. It possible cannot decrypt the entire disc" and then plays the FBI warning before exiting with more errors like that. MoviePlayer just plays the warning and exits without error (kind of annoying).

I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit desktop 11.04. What else can I try to fix this? I'm having trouble troubleshooting this issue because it seems that every website just says to do the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may have been a problem with the DVD drive, I'm not sure.

After getting a new DVD drive for $20 or so, I had similar issues (although not exactly the same). After I booted into Windows and played the DVD's there, it started to work in Ubuntu.

Someone else mentioned that this is likely because my drive was region free and needed a region set on it. Windows handled this automatically, but it's possible that Ubuntu did not.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried other DVD's? It's possible that there was some other "protection" things done to the dvd structure in an attempt to make it not run in computers

Comment: I actually think it might be a hardware issue, strangely enough. I've looked at my dmesg and found a couple CD-ROM errors. After Googling a bit, I found some other people with a similar issue (mind you, only about four or five people, not a common error). I've made a more thorough post about it [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/178756-cant-play-dvds.html#post843840). I guess I could ask a new question about troubleshooting a CD drive? All the other people have either just now come across this issue, never resolved it, or had it fixed by a distro upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem on a relatively new notebook. I also installed the packages you've mentioned, but I still got this error in VLC:

```
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x0008ecde
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
```

and that:

```
[0xb5300618] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0xb5300618] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0xb5300618] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0xb5300618] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

### How to solve it

I solved it with by setting the region code:

```
regionset /dev/dvd
```

Take a look at your DVD. There is a globe with a number on it. That is the expected region code.

### More information

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code) about region codes
- A good (german) article about it is on [ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/regionset)
- Now the movie works, but the second error message is still on the console. So I guess it is not related to the problem that the movie doesn't play. But as people might google for this message (just as I did), I thought it should be included.
- [libdvdread4 fails to retrieve CSS keys](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/701630) could be a related bug

Answer (score 0):

(just expanding on the above answer, which is correct)

apt-get install regionset

put any cd/dvd with something on it in the player

then run "regionset" without ""

If you're in the USA you'll want to set it to region 1

Comment: This should probably be a comment to the above answer...