# Can't play encrypted DVD on internal DVD-drive, but OK with USB-DVD-drive

Tags: 14.04, video, laptop, encryption, dvd

As stated in the title, I can't play any commercial DVD on my internal DVD-drive on my laptop, but everything works just fine for the same DVD played on an external (USB) DVD-drive.
I've installed *ubuntu-restricted-extras* and used the usual script: `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

I might add that this problem is encountered on 3 different laptops, so it's not a physical problems on my machines (hopefully ;)).

Thanks to anyone who would have a solution... :)

Comment: I've tried with Totem, VLC and even installed XBMC yesterday but this one completely crashed when I tried to play a DVD from the internal DVD drive... :/

Comment: I tried to run the script again, and deleted the ./dvdcss2 folder, but still with no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found myself the answer by launching VLC from the terminal, that gave me:

```
main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

Googling it, I found this: [How to play DVDs after installing the recommended libraries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43445/how-to-play-dvds-after-installing-the-recommended-libraries)

I had to change the region code (though I never actually changed it...) to "2" (Europe) by installing regionset:

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
```

then

```
regionset /dev/sr0
```

Confirming I want to change the region code for this DVD-drive, and setting it to "2".

I guess that doesn't explain what the problem was due to, but anyway, it's working now :)