# VLC unable to play mp4 files downloaded from youtube

Tags: vlc, youtube, mp4

Regarding the above, not sure what happen since previously I could play any files I download from youtube, be it avi or mp4.

Now I cannot play any mp4 file downloaded from youtube but no issue to play any other file format (avi, mov, flv using VLC. Some other mp4 files that was downloaded from different source other than youtube are able to play.

Comment: could you run `vlc -vv *mp4 file of your choice*` in a terminal and look for errors? this might help too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166311/cannot-play-avi-or-mp4-file-in-both-movie-player-and-vlc

Comment: No error message displayed. It just stop after i click on play button.

Comment: same for me. It was working previously but all of sudden stopped now. Guess Google has changed some codecs, not sure

Comment: https://archive.org/download/HardDriveSpinning/HardDriveWebm.mp4 is a Google-free MP4 file with audio you can use for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install all **G streamer** libraries to play different video formats in VLC using this command `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-*`

Answer (score 0):

In the extensions of Google Chrome install "YouTube video downloader" or [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) for Firefox or look at the answers for this question: [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

You will get options to download in different formats like `.webm` (recommended because it uses free audio and video codecs), `.mp4` or `.flv`. The downloaded videos can be played in VLC for example.

Answer (score 0):

try resetting the preferences in Vlc :

`Tools -> Preferences` or using the shortcut `CTRL + P`

It's worth noting that Youtube have both Dash* and non-Dash streams

*(*the stream contains only the Audio or Video stream and never both).*