# Movie Player Error

Tags: video, codecs, camera, totem

I just uploaded a few videos from my camera to my computer and when I try to watch them in "*Movie Player*" it comes up with the error:

> Could not determine type of stream.

What does that mean? Keep in mind that I am just a young girl and while I know a bit about the computer I am not a computer genius. Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu version used please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot play avi or mp4 file in both Movie Player and VLC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/166311/cannot-play-avi-or-mp4-file-in-both-movie-player-and-vlc)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options

1. To use the default movie player install restricted codecs.

Open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

2. The option i HIGHLY RECOMMEND

Open Repository(Software Center)

Search for 'SMplayer'

Install SMplayer.

Open almost any multimedia files with SMplayer, no extra codecs needed!

Comment: Neither option worked.