# Videos not playing properly

Tags: 10.04, video

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I installed VLC media player and played some videos, but it is not playing properly... I tried to play them with Totem Movie Player, but it's also not working properly.

Comment: Hi! This doesn't quite look like a programming question, and should probably be asked on http://superuser.com/ *(I'm guessing it'll be migrated there soon, so it's probably no necessary to re-ask the question there)*

Comment: Can you describe what's the problem? Jerky videos or maybe no video output?

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, it would help if you mention what kind of videos you are trying to play.
To play some type of videos you will need to install ubuntu restricted extras. To install this, Open application -> Ubuntu software center or system -> administration -> synaptic package manager. Search for ubuntu restricted extras (ubuntu-restricted-extras) and install the package.

Alternatively from terminal in command line, install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If it is commercial DVDs and if above steps do not enable video playing, you may need to look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs as well.
You can read more on this here [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-dvd-movies).