# Movie Player has require plugins, claims DVD encrypted

Tags: 11.04, dvd, totem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I've been trying to gain the ability to view DVDs on Ubuntu 11.04. I'm using Movie Player.

I have installed the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package, but when I attempt to play the DVD I receive the following message:

```
Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is 
encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the .deb according to your architecture

[32-Bit](http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.3medibuntu1_i386.deb)

[64-Bit](http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.10-0.3medibuntu1_amd64.deb)

Comment: The command seemed to execute correctly, but same result.

Comment: @FarmBoy can you paste the terminal output ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm working on several problems right now, and I've closed that terminal window. All I recall is that it reported success and no errors.

Comment: @FarmBoy try the update post

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight. In the meantime, this is like black magic, where do you get this? How can I find these answers? What is a .deb?

Comment: @FarmBoy a .deb is a software package for more info see this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29)