# What plugin do i need to get DVD use?

Tags: vlc, codecs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I installed the VLC and despite that, my ubuntu 11.10 does not read
DVDs. What did i do wrong? I installed twice?
Best regards for best answer.

Roman

Answer (score 1):

For playing encripted DVDs use the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`