# How do I install a DVD decryption library?

Tags: dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I recently built a computer running Ubuntu 11.10. It works great, except for one thing. With some video DVDs, when I insert them into my drive, the movie player just says "An error occurred. Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed." My mac plays the DVD just fine. What is a DVD decryption library, and how can I install it? Thanks!

EDIT: I need LEGAL way to do this. All I want is to be able to use this computer as a HTPC!