# DVDs won't play under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: video, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I've installed the restricted extras package (Medibuntu) but I still cannot play a dvd under Ubuntu 12.04. I've loaded VLC, but all I can get in it or in Movie Player is the audio but not the video for a DVD.  I've played DVDs on this old box using Xubunut 9.04 I think.  I can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks,

Van

dvd