# How do I install DVD encryption library in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm trying to play a DVD. When I open up Movie Player, I get a message that encryption library needs to be installed. Can you advise me on what to do so I can play a movie from a DVD on my desktop with Ubuntu 12.04?
Sincerely,
Massimo Sorbara

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04: Play Film / Movie DVDs
Check out this page https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.

> Install libdvdnav4, libdvdread4, gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad, and
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly. (see links on original post. They have
>   already been installed with the media packages incl non-open source
>   components... )
>
> If you would like to play encrypted DVDs (see the legal note above),
>   open the Dash and launch a Terminal.
>
> Type the following into the screen which appears, then press Enter:
>   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh Enter your password to
>   complete the installation.
>
> Alternatively - if you are a bit lazy like myself - rather than typing
>   this command, you can also copy (normal ctrl-c) and paste it (using
>   ctrl-shift-v) directly into the terminal console!

Unfortunately Ubuntu doesn't feature encrypted DVD playing for copyright reasons. Blame the film industry for that.

This  post serves as a bookmark to myself, because I tend to forget these steps every time I install Ubuntu. And honestly, I think 12.04 (Precise Pengolin) is a bit less update friendly than previous versions. All my Ubuntu installations had a few hiccups after updating to 12.04. Mainly video playing, and Flash seemed jerky and crashed frequently. Since I made fresh complete re-installs with 64bit 12.04, these annoying bugs seem gone...

I also used that occasion to install the 64-bit version on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge. Overall impression, much smoother, better video, sound, no crashes, no trouble with Flash... I haven't speed-tested my previous installation, so I can't run benchmark comparisons, but the 64-bit feels faster.

Another reminder to myself: the great Ubuntu Multimedia overview page by the German Ubuntuusers.de
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Multimedia
Posted by Moritz Schroeder at Sunday, June 03, 2012