# Why does DVD playback still not work after installing libdvdcss2?

Tags: 12.04, dvd, multimedia, codecs

I have installed libdvdcss2, but I still get this error when trying to play DVDs:

[image]

libdvdread4 was installed by default (This is a new System76 Pangolin Performance). I ran the install-css.sh script, and it completed with no problems.

I can confirm that libdvdread4 and libdvdcss2 are installed:

```
mac9416@charlotte:~$ dpkg -l | grep dvdcss
ii  libdvdcss2                                 1.2.12-0.0medibuntu1                    Simple foundation for reading DVDs - runtime libraries
mac9416@charlotte:~$ dpkg -l | grep dvdread
ii  libdvdread4                                4.2.0-1ubuntu3                          library for reading DVDs
```

Comment: Try installing libdvdread4, from this related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies?rq=1

Comment: How did you install it? What does `dpkg -l | grep dvdcss` show?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I've added information to my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) on the Ubuntu Documentation site were quite right. As david6 pointed out, I simply needed to read further down the page and set the region code.

### The process:

**1. Install libdvdcss**

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

(libdvdread4 came installed with the laptop.)

**2. Set my region code**

After making sure the universe repositories were enabled:

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
```

Before setting my region code, I read the regionset documentation at /usr/share/doc/regionset/README.

```
sudo regionset
```

I set my region to 0, North America.

**3. Fix poor playback**

After setting my region code, playback was possible, but the video was very distorted. So I read further down the [DVD playback page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs). Deleting ~/.dvdcss/ did the trick.

```
rm -R ~/.dvdcss/
```

---

Playback still isn't perfect... In Totem media player, the menu is slightly distorted, and in VLC I have to disable menus entirely. But once the video is rolling, everything works fine. Thank you [January](https://askubuntu.com/users/83703/january) and [david6](https://askubuntu.com/users/34576/david6) for your help!

Comment: there's just one additional thing I had to do. I was not able to set the region because the dvd wouldn't be read at all (could not read /dev/dvd). There was no dvd folder in /dev so I created a symbolic link using "cd /dev" then "sudo ln -s sr0 dvd" (without the quotes off course) Otherwise thank you very much

Comment: As an anonymous user [pointed out](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/210530): "According to the region codes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code Zero is not a region code - it is a non region code." I'll add to this that while, as far as I know, using 0 here may be the best thing to do, someone who *does* want to specify the region code for North America should use 1 instead of 0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_codes#Region_codes_and_countries).

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Try re-installing **all** DVD support:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: Should I remove the three packages first? If so, I'll give it a try tomorrow when I have an unlimited internet connection.

Comment: Yes, first remove then install.  Also make sure you are fully updated as well.

Comment: I removed the three packages (which also removed quite a few dependencies), then reinstalled them. But I'm still getting the same error. I also tried using dpkg-reconfigure on the packages.

Comment: I have those exact versions installed, on having no issues with DVD playback.  What other factor could be affecting this?  Region codes?  Video player (software)?  etc.

Comment: Region codes could have something to do with it... I'll investigate that further. It's probably not the player. I've tried Totem and VLC. VLC doesn't throw an error: it just croaks. The command-line errors just spew "failed to decrypt" messages. I guess the final thing could be the optical drive... but what are the odds of that? I'll find out when I install XP in a Virtualbox later this week.

Comment: Bingo on the region code. I'll be posting my final solution... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it was just region set all the time I followed the steps on the following site which then got it working for me :) I still can't understand why I didn't have to use it on the last version of ubuntu but oh well at least it works and I know to look at it next time if I need to. 
Use the following link for steps...
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-switch-change-alter-dvd-region-code/