# CD/DVD burner does not recognize any DVDs

Tags: 13.04, dvd, burning

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and it no longer recognizes DVDs, either commercial or recordable DVD+R. Cds read and write just fine. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1453314)? It mentions the  libdvdcss, which you may be able to download from [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/). Also, another user suggested physically removing the optical drive and plugging it back in while the computer was off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/185587/why-does-dvd-playback-still-not-work-after-installing-libdvdcss2

Comment: I've downloaded the latest libdvdcss-1.2.13.tar.bz2. I'm a linux newbie, what do I do with this file now?

Comment: Why not just install it from the repositories?

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu) is the tutorial to install Medibuntu, which includes the latest libdvdcss library. In the tutorial, you will add the entire repository, and then have several options for choosing which libraries you would like to install.

Comment: I am not convinced libdvdcss will help here, as the OP says DVD+Rs don't work either.

Comment: same problem with me. after installing 13.04, Drive not respond to CD and DVD. Post a question but no answer. before installing I burn 3 DVDs and Also install ubuntu form DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong driver. Go to Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers and use any drivers there.