# Can't read dvd in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

My laptop has Xubuntu 12.04 installed and I can't read dvds burned in my dvd recorder.

To read my dvds, I had to use a external USB dvd driver (in xubuntu). Using dsmeg, I got this message:

> dmesg | grep "sr0"

```
[11793.286196] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[11793.286202] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[11793.286211] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: Cannot read medium - unknown format
[11793.286221] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[11793.286240] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
```

My laptop is an Asus N43SN.

Comment: Those answering are assuming you are trying to read copies of commercial DVD's, but I'm not so sure. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

There are other answers assuming that your question has to do with commercial DVD's, but you say these are DVD's you have burned yourself.

Assuming these are simply DVD's on which you have recorded you own data:

I've also experienced strange I/O errors when trying to read media I've recorded my self. (Windows and Ubuntu, as I recall).

I found that I had to record to media recommended by the manufacturer of the drive doing the burning. While I had hoped that everything would be as interchangeable as floppy disks and hard drives, optical media apparently have more compatibility problems due to different formats and different media designs. I also found that the cheapest blank media are cheap for a reason.

I suggest that you try burning a couple of blank DVD's from several manufacturers and see if you can find one that produces reliable copies. the documentation or web site of your burner's manufacturer may hold some media recommendations, too.

Answer (score 1):

You prob do have ubuntu-restrictive-extras installed already if you don't.
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Now to install the dvd decryption library 
`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`
Now execute `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh` from terminal 
Rebooting may be necessary 
Hopefully this should help

Answer (score 0):

Three packages, and three packages only, are required to decode DVDs in Ubuntu.

> `sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4`
>
> *Note: To paste in the terminal, DO NOT use Ctrl+V. Use Ctrl+Shift+V. The same applies to copying and cutting.
>
> You will be prompted for your password. When you provide it, no dots,
>   stars, or other characters will appear in place of the letters. This
>   is normal. Proceed and hit enter.

[Source](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu/)