# Ubuntu 12.04 will not play DVDs

Tags: 12.04, dvd

First off, I'm not just a newbie, I'm clueless! So your answers will need to be in complete idiot language (let's say I'm computer savvy, and I can follow directions, but I've never programmed anything and assume I don't understand any abbreviations. So why am I running Linux? Because Windows was driving me nuts and my friend managed to convince me. day-to-day operations, we're doing fine, but when it comes to problems, I've got no clue what I'm doing!)

So here's what's going on, my machine is an HP pavilion dv6, my optical drive is a standard cd/dvdrw, when i load an audio cd of any type (burned, official, etc,..) I have no problems, when I pop in a dvd - i get nothing. the dvd icon comes up in my launch tray, when I open VLC player I can find the dvd in the folder... but it won't play. I can watch movies I've downloaded with no problem, I can also watch movies off an external hard drive.

The only thing I've tried is removing VLC and reinstalling, and I tried installing a different player (gnome maybe? I don't remember). However, none of them work.

Again, I can follow directions, but you need to be very specific and don't assume I know anything going in. (I mean, I know *basic* stuff, but nothing too technical.)

PLEASE HELP!!! MY KIDS ARE DRIVING ME CRAZY!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies

Answer (score 5):

Try pointing VLC to `/dev/sr0` instead of `/dev/dvd` when you open a DVD (CTRL+D). Also, did you install **libdvdcss**? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Answer (score 0):

A reason for this could be that you have not installed the codecs for reading encrypted DVD's. Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and look for 'libdvdcss' and 'libdvdread4' and install them.
As far as I know they are not installed by default, since it is based on closed source and therefore not in the philosophy of open-source software.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but i couldnt find a more up-to-date one, thaat i could reply on. I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and couldnt get DVDs to run after reinstalling the operating system. I had installed the restricted extras and livbdvdcss, but it still wasnt working.

In the end I connected the screen via the graphics card and DVDs now play in VLC (but not movie player). The screen had been connected to the motherboard directly.

I am sure this isnt actually the solution to the problem, but the information might be useful to solving the problem.

Thanks