# Why does my optical drive not play commercial dvds?

Tags: dvd

I'm very new to Ubuntu having just replaced a faulty  Windows 7 on my Sony Viao. I now find that my DVD drive will not play commercial movie DVDs. I have loaded the recommended files. I can use home-made DVD-R no problem, but with the commercial DVDs, the drive makes a loud clicking noise and eventually stops without VLC opening. On a single layer movie disc, VLC reported a blank disc. Any ideas?

Comment: You have tried more than one movie? Have you made sure all the DVD codecs are installed? Of course, the "loud clicking" tells me your dvd drive MAY be failing. Have you tried using an external DVD drive?

Comment: While an optical drive may produce sound in frequent seeking, clicking is an indication of a hardware failure. The disc may be bent and have become unstable.

Comment: Yea, kind of my thoughts too. Thats why I suggested testing with a different disc & a different drive. Thanks for confirming my own suspicions getdvdjk

Answer (score 2):

Because commercial dvd's are encrypted, to be able to read them you need to install some codecs.

Open terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

you may have to enter those commands separately, and you may have to reboot.

Comment: Possible source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and add the VideoLAN Repository with one long command (execute with root rights):

> echo "deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list; apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 6BCA5E4DB84288D9; apt-get update

After that install the libdvdcss2 package with `sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2`.

Comment: Medibuntu is no more so this is probably not an option at this point :(

Comment: @shaneonabike I edited the answer so it uses the VideoLAN repository to recieve libdvdcss2.