# Unable to play commercial DVD in Lenovo E555 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vlc, dvd, 16.04

I have installed both `vlc` and `libdvd-pkg` on my Lenovo E555 ThinkPad. I have also run the command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

In Ubuntu 15.10 that seemed to work for playing encrypted DVD's, but on my fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, I just see this when I try and play a commercial DVD

[image]

It works flawlessly playing a regular  DVD with an MP4 file on it, the problem only seems to occur with commercial DVD's.

---

In some other answers to this similar question it was suggested to use

`sudo apt-get install libdvdread4`

and to then run

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

However this dose not work in this case since the install-css.sh file dose not exist in the /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4 directory.

[image]

---

In some other cases it was pointed out that the region for playing DVD's must be set. In my case here in Eugene, OR, USA the region needs to be set to 1 in order to playback DVD's published for the US and Canada. From `regionset` I see my drive is set properly.

[image]

---

I have now tried an external DVD player and it seems to work fine. This now makes me think that the issue is more of a driver issue.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E550 laptop with an AMD A10 processor in it. From `sudo lshw -C disk` I get the following hardware info for my cdrom:

[image]

Currently I have no clue as to where to go from here. Is this a driver issue, or something else?

Any suggestions on how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my optical drive not play commercial dvds?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247502/why-does-my-optical-drive-not-play-commercial-dvds)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Comment: @Thomas W. The solutions in the possible duplicate solutions do not seem to apply here since the _/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh_ file dose not appere after the installation to the libdvdread4.

Comment: I have been struggling with the same issue for months on LENOVO Z500. Could it be something with our DVD players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS being available at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ this seams to not be the issue that it once was for me.  Besides, I've since move into the 21<sup>st</sup> century and don't use DVD's or CD's anymore and now run a dell E7470 now which has no internal player for Blueray, DVD's or CD's.

My resolve at the time was to just settled with the idea that my disk players drivers were not at the time easily available.

As it was for me in this case I threw this one on the *back burner* of the problem solving engine of life. Sometimes when a problem gets place on the *back burner* for too long the problem fails to remain relevant and thus just fades away from existence leaving nothing left to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I just install Ubuntu 16.04, the file /install-css.sh doesn't exist,I use a file in a usr/share/doc/libdvdread4 from linux mint partition and copy it to the same folder in Ubuntu and It's work.

Maybe you can look for file in internte and paste the file in the folder of Ubuntu.

usr/share/doc/libdvdread4

And run the: sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh

Comment: I gave that a try, when I ran the `install-css.sh` script it seemed to run, but I got the warning of  `dpkg: warning: downgrading libdvdcss2:amd64 from 1.4.0-1~local to 1.2.13-0`

Comment: That did not seem to work, this caused the following dependency to not be met `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdvdcss-dev : Depends: libdvdcss2 (= 1.4.0-1~local)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: It is my understanding that since 15.10 `libdvd-pkg` has replaced the need for using the `install-css.sh` script.

Comment: I copied the install-css.sh from my Ubuntu 14.04 into my Ubuntu 16.04, and after run it, I can play encrypted dvd. So this technique works

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problems.  The solution was 2 parts.  Part 1 is to install the Quicktime drivers: -lib and -dvd [use synaptic for this], and to ensure the VLC install is complete and up to date.  Part 2 is to ensure your dvd drive can process the blocks [my old dvd drive could not, so I bought a new one]. Now, all problems solved.

Comment: rob grune, your answer is opaque: Where and how does one install QuickTime drivers for Ubuntu?

Comment: install Synaptic. search for everything Quicktime.

Comment: Where and how does one install Synaptic for Ubuntu? How does one "search for everything Quicktime?"

Comment: are you running ubuntu?  you do not see "ubuntu software" icon anywhere?  if not, suggest you fresh install ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu 18.10. Yes, however your answer would be improved by  being explicit. For example, you could install software using: a deb file, snap, apt, apt-get, or aptitude, the Gnome software installer, one could compile from source, one could install a package from within another program (e.g. CTAN packages, CRAN packages, etc.). Moreover, *different versions* of the same software may be installed depending on the particular source/method. You should edit your answer to make your directives explicit.

Comment: explicit:  click "ubuntu software" icon; search for "synaptic" and install.  click "synaptic" icon, search for "quicktime"; choose all quicktime items, click "apply" at top of page; reboot your machine. try your cd.