# DVD won't play but CD'S will

Tags: 12.04, dvd, cd

DVD won't play but CD'S will in my disc drive all drivers are installed still not working not sure on the problem is it is a new disc drive and worked fine on windows xp any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: If it played dvds fine with windows this answer should fix your problems http://askubuntu.com/a/503/71679

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be more of a hardware issue... If I understand, you have a CD drive that is only compatible with CDs instead of DVDs, which only newer drives will allow. DVDs are dual-layered, and thus, allows more data to be stored. Some drives are unable to read DVDs because of this.

Comment: They did say it worked on windows

Comment: well it did play dvd's at first and will play blank discs but not dvds