# Can not play DVDs on Ubuntu

Tags: dvd, media

On Ubuntu 12.04 I can't play DVDs in VLC, the native DVD player, or Parole media play. I must be missing something.

What libraries/codecs do I need etc.? Where do I get them? Where do I find out where to get them?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies) question? - also have you tried installing [`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install package *ubuntu-restricted-extras*:

*sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras*

then run:

*sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh*

to install *libdvdcss2* library, that is not included in offical repos due to legal reasons. Finally install your favorite DVD player if you haven't done it yet. Now all DVD movies should play like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! It really worked like a charm. How did you know? I understand the commands, but the arguments -- how do you figure that out?