# encrypted dvd not plaing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dvd

In Ubuntu 12.04 -all DVDs were working. After clean upgrade to 14.04 LTS - encrypted DVDs are not working (with VLC and Videos) but non-encrypted DVDs are working. All suggested "Restricted extras", region code were installed - still not working. Any video from Video shop - not playing. Please Help as I'm not an expert (all I can do is highlight and paste to Terminal) ??

Comment: This may already have an answer here: [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Answer (score 2):

To enable encrypted DVD's use the following command;

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4



sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```