# ubuntu 14.04 won't open DVD's

Tags: 14.04

ubuntu 14.04 won't play DVD's.
I have installed all the "Restricted", libdvdread4, libdvdnav4, etc.etc. regionset is also okay. none of the ubuntu players will open the DVD's. On the same PC, other Hard drive, Windows 8.1 plays without problem.Slowly at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: Have you also installed libdvdcss? It is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/500/367990). Note that it might be not totally legal, depending on where you live...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the VLC player? That is normally the best option for playing anything that won't play with the other videoplayers.

Can't you play any dvd's or is it just certain ones that won't play? Some dvds come with a really nasty copy-protection and I don't get them to play with the normal ubuntu video player either (so far anything worked with VLC, though).

And what happens if you try to open the dvd? Do you get an error message of any kind?