# external CD/DVD drive Samsung SE-208GB not working properly in Ubuntu

Tags: dvd, cd-drive

My new external CD/DVD drive Samsung SE-208GB is not working properly on mini PC with Ubuntu 14.04. Audio CDs play OK, DVDs play with difficulty (vibrations, higher noise), or not at all - it throws an error after a few seconds of noise. When I connected it to my old notebook HP Pavilion with Windows Vista, it is working OK (silent run) - both audio CD and DVDs.

The same bad behaviour on two mini PC with Ubuntu 14.04: one Intel NUC, another ZOTAC ZBOX nano.
Players used: VLC media player, Videos.

How can I fix it, or how workaround is for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question in an older related question: "DVD not playing properly" - it is a "restricted format" issue. The related documents helped.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).