# Import VLC Codex from Mint to 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, vlc, cinnamon

Is it possible to import VLC Codex used in LinuxMint 17.3 Cinnamon to Ubuntu 14.04.1 ?  I tried to play my new DVD from Billy Blanks ( Taebo Boot Camp ) in VLC -  it wouldn't play.  Then I tried it again on a different System running with LinuxMint ( Rosa )17.3 Cinnamon.  The DVD played perfectly !!!

Can anyone tell me if I can import a Codex,  or should I rather install Cinnamon ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it wouldn't play" - any error messages ? Are you sure you're actually using VLC ? Does it happen only with that that DVD, or with other DVD's and media too ?

Comment: Oh thanx for the quick reply JonasCz.  No it gives no error message,  it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Try this: [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/500) - does it work after you follow the instructions in the answer there ?

Comment: This DVD is burned in Country Code " O ",  so recognizeable by ALL DVD Players,  well almost all ;-) Not by THIS one - lol

Comment: Did you try the link in my last comment ? Does it work for you ?

Comment: Thanx JonasCZ.  It works now !!!  I have downloaded this File preciously,  but didn't install it.  That is the second command.  I thank u very much !!!