# Unable to watch a DVD on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dvd

I'm not able to read any of my dvds

I know this question has already been asked but never found a question that gived an answer.

I already tried [how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

I did `sudo lshw -C disk`

```
:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
       vendor: Toshiba
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 2D
       serial: 45NQT2GLT
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096 signature=00091d0a
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
       vendor: PLDS
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       logical name: /media/antoine/NAVY_NCIS
       version: DD11
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
          logical name: /media/antoine/NAVY_NCIS
          configuration: mount.fstype=udf mount.options=ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=77,iocharset=utf8 state=mounted
```

Comment: There are seven different answers on that link. Which one(s) have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different third party media player that has codecs to watch encrypted movies. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is a popular one that you could try.

Comment: he attach link have vlc player http://askubuntu.com/a/503/464430