# How can I access a DVD in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: dvd

I just inserted a DVD in my PC running Ubuntu 16.04. I am a new user of this OS. How can I access my DVD?

Comment: no i am unable to see where from where i access my dvd drive

Comment: how i can move to your address ( /dev/sr0) i cant find that? where it is.

Answer (score 1):

The DVD is mounted at `/dev/sr0` You can check if the DVD is mounted there by opening the Disks application. If the DVD is mounted, you can browse the files from the DVD content's folder in the `/mnt` directory. The DVD content's folder in the `/mnt` directory has an emblem of a DVD disk superimposed on the folder icon it to help you identify it.

Alternatively if the DVD is mounted you can also browse the files on it by right-clicking the DVD's icon in the Launcher and selecting *Open* from the context menu.

Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies/892167#892167).