# How do I play DVDs in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, vlc, dvd, drm

I need to watch a DVD for school, but when I try to watch it in `VLC`, I get this error:

```
Playback failure:
VLC cannot set the DVD's title. It possibly cannot decrypt the entire disc.
Playback failure:
VLC cannot set the DVD's title. It possibly cannot decrypt the entire disc.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///media/curticegough/PHYSICAL_DVD_3/VIDEO_TS/'. Check the log for details.
```

If I open it in `nautiuls`, I get this error:

```
This location could not be displayed

Sorry, could not display all the contents of “PHYSICAL_DVD_3”: Error 
when getting information for file 
'/media/curticegough/PHYSICAL_DVD_3/VIDEO_TS.IFO': Input/output error
```

I already know about DRM and what it is, but I don't know how to get around it.

I also already have all of the usual codecs, including `libdvdnav4`, `libdvdread4`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`, `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`, `dvdcss2`, `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `libdvd-pkg`.

I also have `regionset` installed just in case I need to use it for some reason.

**How do I play my DVD???**

Comment: Have you tries Ubuntu's video player?

Comment: @George Yes I have.  But that shouldn't matter.  VLC should do just as much as Ubuntu's player would and more.

Comment: Are you sure the DVD isn't damaged or corrupted? Does it play okay in another player?

Comment: *CarlH Yes.  The disk is fine.  It works perfectly in my Panasonic Blu-ray player, and in MacOS and Windows.

Comment: Perhaps VLC is the issue

Comment: @George there is nothing wrong with VLC.  If it were just a problem with the player then it should work in Videos and open in Nautilus.  It doesn't work in anything.  **_Ubuntu_** cannot decrypt the disc.

Comment: Did you `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg` after installing the package?

Comment: @JorgeCastro Yes.

Comment: Does playing other DVDs work?

Comment: @RobieBasak some work, but most of them give the same error.

Comment: You mentioned that the disc works fine in MacOS and Windows. Is this *on the same hardware* as you are using when Ubuntu fails? If not, is it possible that the hardware on which you're running Ubuntu is not capable of reading some category of discs - perhaps more marginal quality ones? To eliminate this, can you check to see if the failing disc works on Ubuntu on some other machine using the live image?

Comment: @RobieBasak I used to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu on the same laptop.  It is not a problem with the hardware.

Comment: Can you describe how you have eliminated the possibility of a hardware problem?

Comment: @RobieBasak It used to work fine on the same laptop under windows, and other DVD's work just fine.  It is not a problem with the disk however, because it plays normally in my blu-ray player for the TV and on my iMac.  The error I recieved said that Ubuntu couldn't decrypt the disk.

Comment: Was the installation of `libdvdcss` via `libdvd-pkg` successful? Did you go through the [Troubleshooting section of the DVD Playback page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Troubleshooting)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes the installation was successful and I did go through the troubleshooting section on the wiki.

Comment: Could you do some basic libdvdcss debugging for starters  as described here - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1440147&p=9037249&viewfull=1#post9037249   Then paste the log  on https://paste.ubuntu.com/ & post a link so I can look at. Follow instructions completely, i.e. insert disc, close out any pop up or player, delete the .dvdcss folder & THEN run commands. Irregardless of which command you use to open vlc you must use the exports first (post may not be clear on that..

Comment: Is your disc a Dual-Layer disc? Some players will refuse to play these (like the one in my old laptop). Note that dual-layer isn't the same as double-sided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Answer (score 1):

As already someone told you in the comments, you apparently did not type this command after installing the packages: sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg.
For a more extensive answer (with screenshots) see [How to Play DVD in Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04 and 14.04](https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/)

Answer (score 0):

According to  [this site](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu:) , you must run

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
```

in a terminal, then open VLC, and open the disc. Keep in mind the the packages are non-free.Also if that doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

which is the instructions for Ubuntu 15.04 and later according to  [this site.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)
 You might also want to try a different disc, to check if it is your computer or the DVD itself. Rebooting may also help.
If all else fails, try using something like `brasero` to create an ISO of the disk, then open the ISO in VLC. Keep in mind that it may take a while.