# VLC Media Player Won't Play DVD's

Tags: vlc

I can't play a DVD on vlc, it just won't play. I tried downloading libdvdread4 but that won't help. I tried the solutions on [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies) but again it involved downloading libdvdread4. when I try,  I get an error saying "libdvdread4 is already the newest version."

Comment: is this a production DVD? you need libdvdcss2 (for decoding). libdvdread4, and libdvdnav4

Comment: what about `libdvd-pkg`?

Comment: It says 'Package not found'