# DVD shrinking. Problem installing DVD95 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation, dvd

I am new to the forum. I have used Ubuntu in the past. However, my Command-Line skills are rather limited.

DVD players are becoming obsolete so I decided to make my DVD movies into iso files, including those 'Okay' movies in dual layers.

So I wanted to install DVD95 on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I found a guide to install it, https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/dvd95. However, it does not work at all. The terminal tells me after 'sudo apt-get install...' that;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package dvd95 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dvd95' has no installation candidate'
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and show how to install the application?

I have tried many other possible methods but nothing worked.

Comment: @EliahKagan dvd95 isn't in the multiverse repository for any currently supported version of Ubuntu. The last time it was in the multiverse repository was 14.04. Some of the answers to [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/q/500) are still up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The package is no longer available in Ubuntu 18.04. Yow will have to download the `.deb` file and install it.

Step 1: To download the package, open `terminal` and type

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/d/dvd95/dvd95_1.6p0+git20100528.ef7c-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Step 2: Install the downloaded package

```
sudo dpkg -i dvd95_1.6p0+git20100528.ef7c-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Done. Now you have installed `dvd95`

Comment: I'm not sure if the dependencies can be satisfied. It depends on libav-tools. this package is according to online package search available until xenial

Comment: Thank you but it gives;   dpkg: error processing package dvd95 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dvd95

Comment: If you get that error, run. `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: I think 'sudo apt install -f' just removed dvd95

Comment: Okay. It's fine, run the 2nd step