# unable to play dvd movie disc on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dvd

I am attempting to get an app that can play a dvd movie disc on ubuntu 20.04

I tried VLC, but it just complains that it can't open the disc.

I tried Parole , but I can't even specify /dev/sr0 with Parole.

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Does this answer help ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies/892167#892167

Comment: that did not change anything. same error still happens.

Comment: What error did you get after running VLC?

Comment: VLC error was : playback failure: DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0". Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. check the log for details.