# 20.10 problems with full-upgrade on spamassassin and libdvdcss

Tags: apt, upgrade, spamassassin

After running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` I still have the messages quoted at the end.

How to fix this?

As a workaround, I have installed libdvdcss manually as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies/892167#comment2301159_892167)
and I may try the same with spamassassin but I would prefer to use Ubuntu packages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up spamassassin (3.4.5~pre1-3) ...
Insecure dependency in sprintf while running with -T switch at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30/Config.pm line 62.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30/lib.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30/lib.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/sa-update line 36.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/sa-update line 36.
dpkg: error processing package spamassassin (--configure):
 installed spamassassin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 spamassassin
libdvd-pkg: Downloading orig source...
Attempt to reload Config.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Interface/Storable.pm line 90.
Attempt to reload Config.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Interface/Storable.pm line 90.
I: _
Attempt to reload Config.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Interface/Storable.pm line 90.
Attempt to reload Config.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Interface/Storable.pm line 90.
Attempt to reload Config.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression.pm line 37.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Compression/FileHandle.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Interface/Storable.pm line 90.
/usr/bin/wget --tries=3 --timeout=40 --read-timeout=40 --continue -O libdvdcss_.orig.tar.bz2 \
          http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss//libdvdcss-.tar.bz2 \
        || /usr/bin/uscan --noconf --verbose --rename --destdir=/usr/src/libdvd-pkg --check-dirname-level=0 --force-download --download-current-version /usr/share/libdvd-pkg/debian
--2021-06-18 17:04:09--  http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss//libdvdcss-.tar.bz2
Resolving download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)... 213.36.253.2, 2a01:e0d:1:3:58bf:fa02:c0de:5
Connecting to download.videolan.org (download.videolan.org)|213.36.253.2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-06-18 17:04:09 ERROR 404: Not Found.
/bin/sh: 3: /usr/bin/uscan: not found
make: *** [/usr/share/libdvd-pkg/debian/rules:24: get-orig-source] Error 127
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After many trials this was effective to clean:

```
sudo dpkg --purge spamassassin
sudo dpkg --purge libdvd-pkg
```