# I can't play a commercial dvd on my ubuntu 22.04 laptop

Tags: dvd

I went to “ask ubuntu” and tried the suggestion to install ubuntu restricted extras, and then to install libdvd4. This did not help. Another suggestion was to reset the dvd region code. I typed into the terminal the command sudo regionset /dev/sr0 and was told “command not found”.I tried to use the ubuntu universe repository, but once again after it ran some commands on the terminal, I was told “release not signed, can’t be done securely”, so process was stopped.

Comment: "*This did not help*" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please be specific. Use links to show where you got instructions from. Clearly detail for us the steps you followed. Show us accurate commands and complete error messages. Don't make us guess about what you did, nor speculate about whether you did it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Comment: No. I have tried all the suggestions without any success. To answer the person who said "it did not work" was too vague, my computer kept trying to read the disk drive until after many attempts it stopped. I suspect my drive is not working and I've ordered an external drive to see if this will solve the problem.

Comment: Well, my disk drive was faulty as I found out by getting an external one which did work on my wife's computer but not mine. i did not find any useful suggestions frorm stack exchange. I think my computer is too old for anything to work. Also I think ubuntu 22.04 ia major obstacle. Unless anyone has something  useful to add, this question should be retired. There was really only one answer and it didn't solve the problem. Solution: Get a newer computer, get a better operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some additional packages are required.  I too could not play commercial DVDs until the following

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg libdvdnav4 libdvdread8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Which version of libdvdread may depend upon which version of ubuntu is used.

Comment: Please format commands and terminal output by highlighting the lines and using the {_} icon above the edit window or Ctrl+K keyboard shortcut.