# What media (music and video) players are there?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **This question is present as a matter of historical interest.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will be closed per the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask).**

What media (music and video) players are there?

Please list **one** piece of software per answer, as per this [meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag).

Comment: **A long list of players:** http://appnr.com/category/player

Answer (score 87):

### VLC media player

> VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD, VCD, and various streaming protocols.
>
> Features:
>
> - Simple, fast and powerful media player.
> - Plays everything: Files, Discs, Webcams, Devices and Streams.
> - Plays most codecs with no codec packs needed: MPEG-2, DivX, H.264,
>   MKV, WebM, WMV, MP3...
> - Runs on all platforms: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Unix...
> - Completely Free, 0 spyware, 0 ads and no user tracking.
> - Can do media conversion and streaming.
>
> <sub>From the [VLC media player home page](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).</sub>

To install VLC in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

I was using it the other day to play back 3 720p videos *simultaneously* on a 1 1/2 year old HP notebook. Performance was flawless.

Very advanced customizations/settings.

[image]
[image]

Separate window that includes playlist, file browser, external devices and local network access, internet features (radios, postacasts, Freebox TV channels for registered users)

[image]
[image]

(Using skins reduces the easy access to some of these features.)

VLC media player supports many audio and video compression methods and file formats, including DVD-video, video CD and streaming protocols. It is able to **stream over computer network and to transcode multimedia files**. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player))

[image]
[image]
[image]

It can use extensions, plugins and skins - to be downloaded from [addons.videolan.org](https://addons.videolan.org/browse/cat/).

Among these, some that can find movie subtitles. (More answers on this: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267502/how-do-i-install-vlc-extensions/267504#267504) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47381/programs-to-download-subtitles-for-videos/267509#267509).)

Comment: The best player for any platform. Can't live without it. VLC.

Comment: +1. Although I've defaulted back to Totem for a couple of videos because of funny color problems.

Comment: I have heard that the default VLC build in the repos is always out of date.  Is there a good PPA for keeping VLC the latest and greatest?

Comment: @teeks99 -- that would make a great question post.

Comment: On Windows, it had really bad performance, but on Ubuntu, it works very well.

Comment: *nix system lack of video players. If VLC is best, we are doomed. It just sucks.

Comment: VLC is feature rich, but very bad in terms of memory and CPU usage. I simply don't use it anymore, because it's not usable at all. My awesome machine (ASUS ROG GL502VS, 16 Gb RAM, Intel Quad Core i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz, 8 Gb NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 GPU) and powerful laptop, which works wonderful for many tasks, including training of Machine Learning models on GPU, can't handle VLC, while it works brilliant with SMPlayer or MPlayer. Thus, thumbs down for VLC.

Answer (score 31):

Clementine Music Player - http://www.clementine-player.org/

Clementine is a multiplatform music player. It is inspired by Amarok 1.4, focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing  music.

[image: Clementine screenshot]

Comment: This is really good too. And pretty stable for a 0. release.

Comment: Tested many media players before and still stuck on Winamp with no real solution for Ubuntu. Clementine import my music awesomely fast compared to amarok. Neat GUI. Important feature configurable (like behavior when double click on album). Powerful tag edition embedded. I am a fan. Thank you. you made my day

Comment: For what it's worth, on my work laptop (which has an 8 core i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz and 16GB of RAM and was running Ubuntu 16.04 when I was using Clementine), Clementine's audio playback was pretty poor.  The audio often (probably once every song or every few songs) skipped a second or two

Answer (score 26):

[MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) is also a good one, which makes a good choice for scripting, since it provides feedback when exiting (e.g. `Exiting... (End of file)`), and allows you to react upon this, e.g. mark the file as played.

It's available in Ubuntu, in different flavors (e.g. `mplayer-gui` or just `mplayer`).

You can use VLC for scripting, too:

```
if vlc -f --play-and-exit $FILE | grep 'main playlist: end of playlist, exiting$' ; then
    echo "File played completely."
fi
```

Comment: For Mplayer GUI (Grafical User Interface), I recommend SMPlayer. It's a modern and complete GUI for Mplayer.

Comment: Did you mean "Graphical"?

Comment: `mplayer-gui` is (hopefully temporarily) dead. It wouldn't build against the shared codec libraries so had to be binned. The bug has since been fixed but now the packages have been simplified, it might never return.

Answer (score 19):

Banshee - http://banshee.fm/

Having used several media players for my large music collection I have found this to be the best so far.

[image: Banshee screenshot]

Comment: I have very mixed feelings about Banshee player's quality, design and features. Bottom line -- could (and should, almost *must* be improved (after all Canonical chose that player to replace Rhythmbox)). Lacks genre browsing (why?), not so nice way to manage radio streams and/or audiobooks (no import/export) no nice refresh method. There are many cool features, but these inabilities just ruin my impression. Half cooked.

Answer (score 17):

Smplayer : Great Qt4 GUI front-end for mplayer

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube
```

Can download subtitles

[image]

and can play youtube videos externally reducing the load on the GPU (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/169622/47206), question)
[image]

the toolbar is editable
[image]

subtitles font, position etc are editable
[image]

Comment: Thumbs up for the SMPlayer. So far, the best balance of most efficient (in terms of memory and CPU usage) and feature rich (like, open ISO files, open DVDs, handling various formats).

Comment: Switched to this after VLC gave me audio glitches for x265 videos.

Answer (score 16):

Audacious - http://audacious-media-player.org/

Apparently this is a very lightweight player that can apparently use Winamp skins.

[image: Audacious screenshot]

Comment: how can i see lyrics in audacious?

Answer (score 15):

UMPlayer - http://www.umplayer.com/

Front end for MPlayer, well designed, allowing on the fly skins and well set out preferences including editable shortcuts. Similar to KMPlayer on Windows.
Available in Ubuntu Software Centre.

[image: umplayer default skin]
[image: umplayer modern skin]

Comment: Wait... that's a Windows screenshot...

Comment: **The software seems to be no longer maintained.** @user10962 Act accordingly when you see such things, flag if it's Windows only software, or edit accordingly, at best replace the screenshot.

Answer (score 14):

Rhythmbox - http://rhythmbox.sourceforge.net/

Another contender for managing your music library, I have found it to be a bit cumbersome when tagging mp3 also it does not like to handle a large library (yet again that is my opinion).

[image: Rhythmbox screenshot]

Comment: I wonder how to make Rhythmbox look just like that. All recent versions have a wide separate bar for the title and progress slider.

Answer (score 14):

[Deadbeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/) audio player that has all the features you are describing:
http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/

[image: enzotib screenshot]

[image: deadbeef with file browser]

Recent versions (now 0.6.2) bring it even closer to the purpose of becoming a Foobar2000 alternative by the 'Designer mode' feature that lets you add or remove features. The main addons like the File browser and Infobar (lyrics and biography) can be added in this way.

[image]

[image]

More plugins: http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/plugins.html

Comment: the way it handles media library and playlist makes it the best - install file browser plugin

Comment: deadbeef is much lighter than other music players with comparable (but still inferior) features.

Answer (score 13):

Totem comes as standard on Ubuntu.

[image: Totem screenshot]

Comment: It's name is Totem! - find it here: http://bit.ly/kmI2nx

Answer (score 11):

Quod Libet - http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/

I have never heard of this player before.

[image: Quod Libet screenshot]

Comment: You make this answer yet say you've never heard of this player before...

Comment: I'd recommend against using Quod Libet. I've found it to be buggy and to eat too much RAM.

Answer (score 11):

GNOME Media Player - https://launchpad.net/gnome-media-player

This media player supports the vlc, xine and GStreamer engines for playing media. Since some file formats play well only on a certain engine, this media player was made with 3 engines, so that the user can select the required engine required for playing a particular file type. It also has an engine auto select mode, in which the player automatically selects the best engine for the particular type of file being played.

[image: GNOME media player screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

Exaile Player - http://www.exaile.org/

Exaile is a music manager and player for GTK+ written in Python

[image: Exaile screenshot]

Comment: [posted already](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there/42543#42543) in this question.

Comment: Yeah , but I was the first one.

Comment: as this is community wiki, you'll not get your rep for upvotes anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Guayadeque - http://guayadeque.org/forums/index.php?p=/wiki/page/home

Another great music playing application, constant updates from the author who does all of the work himself, and takes on board suggestions from users.

[image: Guayadeque screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

If your music collections is on a remote server (very handy to control you music from everywhere in the house) then Music Player Daemon (mpd) is a go to, full documentation and list of client there:
[mpd](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki)

Answer (score 7):

A nice and interesting media player: [Gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org/). Its web describes it as:

> An open-source jukebox for large collections of mp3/ogg/flac/mpc/ape files, written in perl.

It has a nice GUI. The default view shows the artists and bands from your collection and for the selected item it shows the list of albums including a thumbnail of the coverart (if available). It also offers *themes* so that it looks like Exaile, QuodLibet or Rhythmbox.

[image: Gmusicbrowser screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Gnome Media Player is new and doesn't come with too many features but for just playing movies, its great. It supports the VLC, Xine and Gstreamer engines for playing media. It also has the ability to switch between the engines, and an engine auto select mode which automatically selects the best engine for playing a particular type of file.

It's in the Ubuntu 10.10 official repositories so you can search for it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

For Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, install it using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-media-player-development/development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-media-player
```

Answer (score 5):

Boxee - http://www.boxee.tv

It's a media center (in my opinion the best there is) for Linux, Windows and  Mac.
It supports lots of video / music portals as well as DVD, CD and local media in general.

It's currently not available in the Software center but I listed an idea on getsatisfaction: http://getsatisfaction.com/boxee/topics/add_boxee_to_the_ubuntu_software_center

Available for 32 bit and 64 bit as a *.deb file.

[image: Boxee screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

[Beatbox](https://launchpad.net/beat-box/) is the music player under active development for the ElementaryOS project.

It offers:

- Automatic and manually arranged playlists
- Last.fm support (scrobbler + similar tracks)
- A play queue
- An Equalizer with presets and custom settings support
- A slick interface with 3 views

[image: Beatbox Screenshot]

Comment: Seems like the project is quite dead...

Answer (score 4):

There is GNOME MPlayer, a GTK+ frontend to MPlayer. Among its features are support for hardware acceleration and subtitles.

[image: gnome-mplayer screenshot]
[image]

Comment: Already mentioned in this question.

Comment: @ulidtko: no, there's Gnome Media Player, which is a different project.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend installing SMplayer instead of VLC. SMPlayer supports VDPAU. (I heard that VLC also supports VDPAU, but I have not been able to find any PPAs with a VLC package that supports VDPAU / VAAPI without errors.)

**Glossary:**

[VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU): The VDPAU API allows video programs to offload portions of the video decoding process and video post-processing to the GPU video hardware.

[VAAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAAPI): VAAPI is an open source software library ("libVA") and the API specification which provides access to graphics hardware (GPU) acceleration for video processing on Linux and Unix-based operating systems. Accelerated processing includes video decoding, video encoding, subpicture blending and rendering.

Comment: vlc along smplayer won't hurt

Comment: And VLC in the repos now supports VAAPI / VDPAU.

Answer (score 3):

SMPlayer is recommended as it has a really good interface and uses the superb MPlayer as its backend.
It supports a great variety of codecs, and plays practically any major format you throw at it. It uses Qt, and integrates reasonably well with an Ubuntu desktop.

You can install SMPlayer by either searching via Software Center or by running Terminal and passing the command:
 `sudo apt-get install smplayer`

Answer (score 3):

Listen Music Player - http://www.listen-project.org/

[image: Listen screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

XMMS - http://www.xmms.org/

This looks similar to Audacious judging by the screenshots, another player I have not used.

Answer (score 3):

Bangarang Media Player - http://gitorious.org/bangarang

Offers a media—audio and video—player with a lightweight interface

[image: Bangarang screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Miro: http://www.getmiro.com/

It may be more of a podcatcher (or at least started off as one) that even supports bittorrent but it does play media as well.

[image: Miro screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Totem Movie Player (the default movie player in Ubuntu) is pretty good. You just need to get all the required codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Bluemindo : http://bluemindo.codingteam.net/

Bluemindo Ubuntu Packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bluemindo

Bluemindo is a really simple yet powerful audio player in Python/PyGTK, using GStreamer.

[image: Bluemindo screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This is only a client for mpd, but I had to post it: [ncmpcpp](http://unkart.ovh.org/ncmpcpp/). Fast, nice features (library, automated lyrics download, playlists manager, tag editor), and can be used without X.

[image: ncmpcpp screenshot]

Comment: please, add a few more info for interested ignorants like me

Answer (score 2):

**Foobnix**

http://www.foobnix.com/welcome?lang=en

[image]

*Main features player*

- Support for CUE (also wv, iso.wv) is
  the best under Linux (zavlab)
- Formats MP3, MP4, AAC, CD Audio, WMA,
  Vorbis, FLAC, WavPack, WAV, AIFF,
  Musepack, Speex, AU, SND ...
- Converter any format to any (mp3,
  ogg, mp2, ac3, m4a, wav)
- Scrobbler tags with music and radio
- Find and play music and videos
- Equalizer
- Online music download manager
- Shortcuts
- Displays the album cover, lyrics,
  photo artist
- Integration with VKontakte
  (displaying all the friends and their
  music, downloading music from the
  group vkontakte)
- Integration with Last.FM (Show plays
  the best songs, favorite songs,
  artists)

and great support for russian tags :-)

Answer (score 2):

(Apparently Linux is not an officially supported port of **Songbird** anymore. You can still get untested nightly build from [here](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Articles/Builds/Contributed_Builds#Linux), but YMMV)

[image: songbird screenshot]

Comment: Since this a community wiki and @user18027 didn't respond, I went ahead and edited it. Feel free to re-edit if you don't agree with my revision.

Comment: Whilst Songbird is a great Music Library application the developers of it have stopped making it for Linux.

Comment: @scouser73: apparently they still make nightly builds available [here](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Articles/Builds/Contributed_Builds#Linux), but I'll write a warning on the post.

Answer (score 2):

[XBMC](https://cmdevweb.sscno.nmci.navy.mil/tmtrack/tmtrack.dll?) works great on HTPC.

[image: Confluence Skin]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Qmmp is a Qt audio player which provides a user interface similar to Winamp or Xmms. To install Qmmp in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install qmmp
```

Qmmp can read almost any audio format such as:

- MPEG1 layer 2/3
- Ogg Vorbis
- Native FLAC/Ogg FLAC
- WavePack
- CD Audio
- WMA, Monkey's Audio (and other formats provided by FFmpeg library)

This player supports a wide range of plugins such as:

**DSP effects**

- BS2B effect
- sample rate conversion
- LADSPA effects (A very large collection of Open Source DSP plugins)
- extra stereo
- crossfade

Also, it's worth noting that Qmmp supports Winamp 2.x skins.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a freeware (non open source) windows application, and so require `wine` to be run, I think that [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) is yet one of the best audio playes out there.

It supports a wide number of formats (MP3, MP4, AAC, CD Audio, WMA, Vorbis, FLAC, WavPack, WAV, AIFF, Musepack, Speex, AU, SND and more with additional components).

It has advanced tagging capabilities.

And most important to me, it supports the playing of single-wav-file CDs through CUE sheets to switch between tracks.

[image: Foobar2000 screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, for the sole purpose to play something fast and easy with a "right-click/open with..." or by relating certain files to a player, there is also the [Dragon Player](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dragonplayer/) Which does an awesome and lightweight thus fast work, it can play both video/audio files (mp3/wav/avi/mpg, etc.) and/or discs (CD/VCD/DVD, etc.)

It uses KDE so you may need to install certain dependencies if you are not using KDE and not already installed, afterwards you'll find it fast running on Unity, Gnome and other environments.

It has not a lot of features, which makes of this the cleanest click-to-play media player.

From the site:

> A video player with a different philosophy: Simple, uncluttered
>   interface.
>
> Features:
>
> 1. Plays all video formats supported by Phonon.
> 2. Bundled with a simple web-page KPart.
> 3. Starts quickly. This is the KDE 4 version of the Codeine video
>      player.

A screenshot of Dragon Player in action (don't expect to find anything else of which is shown in the screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Qmmp Player.

To install the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:forkotov02/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qmmp qmmp-plugin-pack
```

Already mentioned in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/183994/47206).

The GUI can use a skin (Winamp-like, see linked answer) or a 'simple' interface, which in fact has a lot more features, including a file browser, and follows the system theme and icons:

[image]

To switch between these two, set as below and restart player:

[image]

Comment: in qmmp 1.3.1 fixed current track text color in the qsui plugin (the simple interface): better visibility with current track colored not just bold.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend xine, it is in the repository and plays HD content with lower resources than VLC.

Answer (score -3):

Real Player - http://uk.real.com/realplayer/other-versions

Music and video Player, well known.

Note :Just for `i386` architecture.

[image: Real Player screenshot]