# How do I install VLC extensions?

Tags: vlc, plugins, extension, paths

[VLC player allows installing extensions, plugins, skins](http://addons.videolan.org/?xsection=home). They have to be copied into a folder: for example, its `.lua` extensions should be in a folder with the same name. Where is that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To install extensions (`.lua`) the needed folder is `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/` for the current user and `/usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/` for all users. I found about it [here](http://totallynoob.com/VLSub-plugin-for-VLC-media-player-how-to-install-and-use-ubuntu-11-10-unity-) and [here](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.8?content=148752).

Once installed, they are to be found under 'View'

[image]

(I put them here for illustration, I do not recommend all of them.)

Skins are installed by going to Tools/Preferences(Ctrl-P) - Interface: 'Use custom skin', and select the skin file.

---

### UPDATE

At least for the moment, *very few* VLSub extensions are really working and are worth trying; and, among these, most are not actively developed, as you can see [here](https://addons.videolan.org/browse/cat/323/ord/top/): the best is **VLSub**, probably the best tool around at the present for downloading subtitles - to the point that recent versions of the player have integrated that addon by default (but in VLC 2.2.2 that is outdated and has stopped working: see below).

**VLC 2.2. has the capability to search and install extensions** within it's settings, under *Tools-Plugins and extensions*:

[image]

Only it doesn't always install the latest version which is needed for the extension to really work, in which case download the script from the developer (for VLSub, [here](https://github.com/exebetche/vlsub)) and install it as indicated in the first part of this answer.

If the addons that come with the player need to be replaced, look for them in `/usr/lib/vlc/lua/extensions/`.

Comment: Here is another system path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/extensions/`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the snap version of VLC on Xubuntu 20.10.

The extensions are located under:

```
/home/[username]/snap/vlc/1700/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that installed the Flatpak version of VLC the path to your extension folder is

```
/home/[username]/.var/app/org.videolan.VLC/data/vlc/lua/extensions
```

(at least on Ubuntu 21.10 using VLC 3.0.16)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry,I don't have enough reputation to comment on the previous answers:

1. 1st answer by **user47206** & edited by Jorge Castro descries two ways to add add-ons (plugins or extensions) to VLC manually by placing their lua files in a certain directory or automatically via tools menu>plugins and extensions which are still valid ways theoretically but directories mentioned in the answer and the comment by Antonio Petricca are now all not working/ obsolete.
2. 2nd Answer by **user1137772** & edited by Nmath shows a new directory /home/[username]/snap/vlc/1700/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/ which needs a little tweak now "I'm using VLC version 3.0.12.1 on ubuntu 21.04 from ubuntu software store" to **/home/[username]/snap/vlc/2103/.local/share/vlc/** "which contains folders **skins2** for vlt file type skins and **lua**/ for different plugins and extensions of lua file types i.e **extensions** like VLsub which is preadded by default now, **playlist** like radiotime also preadded,later it may create other folders inside e.g **sd** for service discovery like TuneIn or **intf** for interface like syncplay which you can add the automatic way".
3. location for **luac** files library extracted from " preadded VLsub = extension" more information from tools menu>plugins and extensions>active extensions is **/snap/vlc/2103/usr/lib/vlc/lua/[folder]** see [evidence image](https://ibb.co/tqF3Ft1) and [evidence image](https://ibb.co/Jd1tFtM) which contains luac files for other preadded add-ons like jamendo and icecast.
4. By default tools>preferences>"advanced"interface>input / Codecs>**disable all lua plugins** is checked and unchecking it will disable those preadded "luac" add-ons (like VLsub, jamendo, and icecast) and the "lua" ones I added (like TuneIn Radio, Jump to time, Sampler_PG "which have only a lua file in /home/[username]/snap/vlc/2103/.local/share/vlc/lua/[folder] !").
5. For me, I added some add-ons automatically and some manually, only extensions appeared in view menu under VLsub ,while service dicovery add-ons added the "automatic way" will appear in playlist left panel and other add-ons e.g. skins, playlist parsers, interface will appear installed only in tools>plugins and extensions :

   - Skins worked only manually for me from native skin by going to tools>preferences>"simple"preferences>look and feel>check use **custom skin** and then browse to your vlt file "automatically downloaded skins will not appear here as .local is hidden directory so you'll have to put them into a visible one" click save and restart VLC. After loading a cusom skin an option will appear in right click menu>interface>select skin, From which you can choose a skin from /home/gandalf/snap/vlc/2103/.local/share/vlc/skins2. 
     Choosing skin2 from tools>preferencec>"advanced"preferences>interface>main interface>skinnable interface "check" caused the player to crash and not be opened anymore except by typing VLC in terminal.
   - Extensions I added automatically "appeared to" work.
   - All other add-ons that I added did not work.