# How to add a VLC extension

Tags: vlc

I want to add Resume Media to VLC but I can't find the path `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/`.

How do I find it using a file manager?

I found the folder where you would place it for all users but it won't let me paste it in. Probably a permissions thing. I don't know enough about the Linux file system to figure this out.

Comment: What happens when you create the path `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions` and put the file there?

Comment: Files and directories starting with a dot are hidden. Ctrl+H in Nautilus and you are good to go.

Comment: Try this --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/267502/how-do-i-install-vlc-extensions

Answer (score 1):

`~/` stands for your "Home" folder. So you'll have to go to *Home* > *.local* > *share* > *vlc* > *lua* > *extensions* folder.

Open *Files* (or Nautilus, the file manager), it should open your home directory by default.

But you won't be able to see the `.local` folder there, it's hidden by default (as it starts with a `.`). You'll have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> first to unhide hidden folders. Then you'll see the `.local` folder there.

Then you'll be able to navigate to your target folder.

Once you're done you may press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> again to hide those folders starting with a `.`.