# Folder navigation - VLC folder

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, directory, vlc, cd-command

Hi im a fairy new linux user

Im trying to navigate to the lua folder in vlc.

When i type

> whereis vlc

It said:

> vlc: /usr/bin/vlc /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc /usr/share/vlc /snap/bin/vlc /usr/share/man/man1/vlc.1.gz

I tried:

> cd /usr/bin/vlc

> cd ./usr/bin/vlc

> cd ~/usr/bin/vlc

Nothing works. How do i get to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereis vlc` outputs the paths to the executable, which is a file. But you can only `cd` to directories.

However, the `lua` directory is at `~/.local/share/vlc/`

```
cd ~/.local/share/vlc/
```

Comment: Thank `~/.local/share/vlc/` was the correct folder and i was able to modify my vlc so it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

*/bin/* normally means an executables directory, so `/bin/vlc` would be an executable file and not a directory

You need to check `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/` and `/usr/lib/vlc/lua/`

Look at here [How do I install VLC extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267502/how-do-i-install-vlc-extensions)