# Light Video Player to download subtitles automatically

Tags: video

Which one is the most lightware video player ?

I watch usually normal videos, with not so high resolution...

Referring to the hardware resources used tell me please do you recommend me a video player which comes with the most common codecs included, or is it possible to use a fast way in Linux to download/install the video and audio codec that I need for the video which I am trying to watch?

If this is possible how can I find in Linux the video codec which I need to see the video?

One of the most important option included would be to search and download subtitles for the video which I am watching to (would be better to search on more subtitles websites).

Thank you.

In my opinion it is not a duplicate of [Programs to download subtitles for videos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47381/programs-to-download-subtitles-for-videos) because the question is about a light video player with the subtitles download feature included too.

Comment: Don't see why this has so much hate (3 downvotes), would be nice of people to ex plane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programs to download subtitles for videos](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47381/programs-to-download-subtitles-for-videos). -- 2 lightweight video players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If light on resources is your top priority, you can run your videos in a terminal with `mplayer`, no GUI == less resources

```
mplayer /path/to/my/video
```

Note: You don't have to type the videos name every time, just type `mplayer` and drag the videos icon on to the terminal.

To choose a custom resolution, swap the `-x` and `-y` values for your resolution. `-fs` starts the video in fullscreen.

```
mplayer /path/to/my/video -fs -x 1280 -y 720
```

Some other use full perimeters include `-nosound` to run muted and `sub /location` for loading sub titles.

```
mplayer /path/to/my/video -nosound sub /location/of/sub/titles
```

To get a list of peramiters type `mplayer` in a terminal or go [this page](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html) for a full manual.

I highly recommend a frontend to set up your video options, even if you don't want to use it for playback, I like `smplayer`

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Heres a quick explination of auto subs, but it must be set up in `smplayer` I could not find any shell commands for this

From the menu go to ->  Subtitles -> Find Subtitles on OpenSubtitles.org  A “Find Subtitles” dialog box will appear. In the Options, set the proxy settings if you are using any. [From here](https://leisurehours.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/automatically-download-subtitles-using-smplayer-in-linux/)

It will automatically search for subtitles on OpenSubtitles.org and display a list of available subtitles. Select any one from list and download that.

For codecs, all most users will ever need (and you should already have) is

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/), it's light with many codecs. Install it:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

To learn how to get subtitles in VLC watch this [video](https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZDq9aEZOZQs&ei=l4SXVcTXG8rTUbDhnrAE&usg=AFQjCNE1U8TbK-9vYJtO3-0avWq_Xt-DCg&sig2=OK_HnJQsCyAPTiEKjmSHnA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24)

You need to install a VLC extension called [VLSub](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.9.13?content=148752).

**INSTALLATION** <sub>[source](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.9.13?content=148752)</sub>:

- click on the [download](http://addons.videolan.org/content/download.php?content=148752&id=1&tan=94996706)
- save the archive and extract the file "vlsub.lua"
- create a directory "extensions" at this location and put the file "vlsub.lua" inside `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/`

Comment: Thank you @Maythux, tell me please is vlc even lighter than mpv, mplayer, SMplayer or Gnome Media player? Unfortunately Gnome Media player doesn't have the feature for subtitles search.

Comment: @XPDIN you are welcome.  If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you really like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark and the little up-arrow http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Excuse me @Maythux, I am asking again, tell me please in your opinion is VLC more lightweight in using hardware resources than mpv, mplayer, SMplayer or Gnome Media player? Unfortunately Gnome Media player doesn't have the feature for subtitles search. Regards.

Comment: This is primarily based opinion and yes i think that, it's slick to use i used it 4 years ago an tried most video players and found VLC the best among them

Answer (score 0):

SMPlayer has this option too, as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/48028/925128) too.

[image]