# Music player that works with a large library of music files

Tags: music-player

I'm looking for a fast and functional music player that can work with a huge library of music files. Banshee is quite OK, however it uses too much resources on my laptop and hangs from time to time. Probably because of my huge library. Rhythmbox was even worse. Exile got broken after some time.

Is there a player that can scan and manage 85 GB of music without much problems? Maybe something like foobar2000 for Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I Use [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/) for managing about 50 GB of my music without any problem. 
It is simple,fast and easy to use.

See here for [Clementine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there/42537#42537).

Full list of available players : 
[What media (music and video) players are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there)

---

**Edit:**
Also you can try [Elementary music player(BeatBox)](https://launchpad.net/beat-box) (For Ubuntu 11.10 and above only).

[image]

See [Webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/elementary-music-player-beatbox-03.html) for installation.

Comment: Clementine seems to be even slower. It scanned library quite well, but it slowed down my system a lot.

Comment: @Karolis: Answer updated.See Above.

Comment: BeatBox needs Gnome 3 so it wont work on 11.04

Comment: @zetah yes true.If you look at the date of my answer , you can see that it used to work in natty but now it needs Gnome3. ( Post updated and thanks for the correction).

Comment: oh, sorry for alarming :) I didn't even noticed that this question was raised from dead

Comment: @zetah don't worry, the answer should have been updated anyway so thanks for the note again:).

Answer (score 3):

gmusicbrowser is the best way, no doubt. Simple, integrated with main menu, lot styles to choice, etc. Take a look!

Comment: I think I like it. Works quite well, though it isn't as good as Banshee at managing library.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for foobar2000 replacement there are 2 options IMHO:

1. Deadbeef that doesn't have media library feature, but follows foobar2000 philosophy
2. QuodLibet in all it's glory - fast, low on resources, handles large libraries and has even more features similar to foobar2000 then Deadbeef

There are some issues of course, like (for QuodLibet):

- ReplayGain: recent foobar2000 versions use EBU R128 standard which on Linux no player has yet implemented. QuodLibet writes RG value in unorthodox tag (can read foobar2000 RG values, but not other way around)
- ALBUMARTIST: mainly MP3 issues - if you write this values with foobar2000 > 1.1.6 then QuodLibet reads it fine, otherwise it's in Perfomer tag
- No DSP and similar processors with QuodLibet, although you can use Jack audio output and use Jack DSP feature
- No Converter, but you can use custom application through QuodLibet plugin system
  ...

probably other things I can't remember now

Comment: It is not true that "Deadbeef doesn't have media library feature" - it can display library with a plugin. I use it for that.

Answer (score 2):

i use **[guayadeque music player](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guayadeque/)**. It is fantastic. I have a music library of 140GB and it is very quick with tons of features, though it is a bit ugly. I mean the interface but i can compensate that with the good features the player have.

Answer (score 1):

I use Guadayeque, Clementine and the new Audacious with Music Library ([Audacious 3.2, Gnome Pie 0.4, Xnoise 0.1.31](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/updates-audacious-32-gnome-pie-04.html)), and all work fine, my music library have 317GB (54799 songs) and all work fine

Answer (score 1):

I have to say after trying pretty much all of the media players the only one that doesn't mess with your file structure or choke on large music collection is "Guayadeque" my collection is nearly 450gigs and it loads fast is easy to setup :-) i always run the latest build from svn and update regularly with no problems.

http://guayadeque.org/forums/index.php?p=/page/installing#InstallSVN

this will give you all the needed dependencies as well as instructions-

also the ppa has just been updated to the latest version too

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install guayadeque

or

sudo apt-get install guayadeque-svn

enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Quod Libet, which is a lightweight music player (although has more "bulk" than Audacious). Currently manages a 35,000 track media library on an older machine without problem.

Also, see this link for a great overview
http://thesimplecomputer.info/choosing-a-linux-music-player/

Answer (score 0):

[DeaDBeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/download.html) is lighter than Clementine, I am using it with 200 GB of music and don't think that it's close to its limits. I use the [file browser plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/plugins/0.5.1/ddb_filebrowser-0.3.zip/download) to access the database.