# Music player with 'searchable' media library ?

Tags: music-player

I have been looking quite few days for that but I have not found an answer. 
I am trying to find a good music player for ubuntu in which I would be able to search the media library like in winamp ( typing te band's or song's name in a search field ).

I have tried this with Banshee but

- it lags a lot when I change the 'selected' album in library
- I cannot find the search field/option in there

Any suggestions/solutions ?

Comment: You might find one in [these answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/42532/3940). I am most happy with Guayadeque - Gmusicbrowser may also suit your needs, just to name two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also try [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/).  I have found it to be blistering fast when it comes to indexing or searching my music library.

Answer (score 7):

**GMusicbrowser** has the ability to "mimic" different audioplayers, like for example iTunes-Style library search. It's pretty lightweight too and does not lag so much like Banshee.

Answer (score 5):

I use rhythmbox and it has a media search function with filters for artist,song,album,genre, etc

Answer (score 3):

Try [Guayadeque](http://guayadeque.org/), it has lots of functions, including search.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) if you also like support for complex queries. Some difficult queries I've used recently in addition to the normal ones (disclaimer: I am one of the devs though):

- all pop songs in my library originally by Bob Dylan not played in the last week
- all Metal or Hip-hop songs from albums in the last decade with an average volume of 98dB or above)...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [aTunes](http://www.atunes.org/), which is a java-based Music Player. Your requested feature is well implemented as well, and you can customize column view(s) for quicker and easier access to our music. You can also list online information about the artist, albums etc..

There are other nice functions, like: OSD, different gui(s), showing online lyrics from an internet-database, adding/playing online-radio-stations, podcast, choice of different input-devices, music statistics etc..

[image: aTunes]

Answer (score 1):

**BeatBox** music player is a new music player for Ubuntu. It's great. It can handle large library. It has many features which others lack. It's in active developing process. 
[Beatbox Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/beat-box)

Answer (score 0):

I need a media player for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 that will connect to my Synology Media Server. It appears that Rhythmbox is unable to do so. The Grilo plugin has no effect. Neither Clementine nor Amarok can do so either. I'm not sure why this is so difficult with Ubuntu Linux. I've spent many hours trying various solutions, none have worked so far.

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question.