# How do I play music from the terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want a command line to play a specific music file in terminal (or script) from my hard-disk. Is it possible without installing extra packages?

Comment: [MoC (Music on Console)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_on_Console) is another option worth exploring. [Here's a guide](http://v1.corenominal.org/howto-setup-moc-music-on-console/) to set this up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the default installation has no way to play audio files from command line, other than using `aplay` on WAV files (`aplay` also support other formats, but the man page is not clear in this regard).

To play, for example, MP3 files, you need restricted codecs available through `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, and a player like `mplayer` or `cvlc`, but there are many other: see [What Media Players Are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there) where text based and GUI based audio players are listed.

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras is considered as default in Ubuntu(as all have to install it with installation or after)i always install them when setting-up Ubuntu.

Comment: The missed `Sox`!

Comment: APlay does not play m4a files... or it does, but it sounds like a dialup connection.

Answer (score 7):

There are players such as [`cmus`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmus), `mpg321`, `ogg123`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several text based Media Players which play in the Terminal, which are not mentioned in "What Media Players Are There?" ---but they will all involve some download.

(You do say "It would be better to do it without installing extra packages" but you do not say it is a definite no-no)

Have a look at http://kmandla.wikispaces.com/search/view/music.

Worthy of special mention are moc and cmus.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo apt-get install moc`and then `mocp`
 in a new terminal window.

This will let you play the selected audio from the terminal.