# What file managers are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

Please, can someone advise me which File Managers that are available to install and use in Ubuntu?

> Please include only one file manager per answer, with the following information:
>
> - Caracteristics and/or features
> - Main differences with the installed by default in Ubuntu (Nautilus, Dolphin, Pacman, etc.)
> - Screenshot
> - How to install and configure as default file manager
> - How to remove and purge configurations restoring the original configuration

Comment: Oo , why neg vote ? is that such a bad Question ?

Comment: Good! I was looking for such post.. Okay I have a query to0.. Which display manager is in Ubuntu 13.04, I'm using 12.04 LTS and want to install that in it! Will you please suggest me how?

Comment: I believe that the negative vote was because your question is very short... This, to me, is NOT a reason to down vote it.

Comment: @SauravKumar  My friend , are you testing me :P .ok fine. its LightDM but whats the matter with it ?

Comment: I have all desktops installed @SauravKumar and almost many of these file managers . Let me tell you something. If you have pure Ubuntu-desktop and you want to install dolphin , only dolphin then Ubuntu will take care of what are the other files required to install to run dolphin safely in Ubuntu.

Comment: @rajagenupula: Actually what I liked most is it searches the file/folder as soon as you start typing, and show the search results.. That was incredible! I didn't get such file manager. But now I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Is there any way I could get that?

Comment: @SauravKumar yes it thunar

Comment: @rajagenupula: No its not! I installed `thunar` (install size around 15MB) and Run `Thunar File Manager` but it is not the thing I am searching..

Comment: @SauravKumar have you checked properly ? because http://postimg.org/image/uyvwlibvx/

Comment: @SauravKumar even it is not that what are you looking for , dont worry I will try to find at my best. The same I have got with nemo also

Comment: @rajagenupula: So you didn't get what I was asking.. When you will type `sank` the file manager in `Ubuntu 13.04` shows only the results matched by `sank` others will be cascaded..

Comment: @SauravKumar Hmm I have found it just now . http://postimg.org/image/v986t9ldf/7f3a0f56/

Comment: @rajagenupula: Yes that is what I was looking for! It is default in `Ubuntu 13.04` could you please tell me how can I get it on `Ubuntu 12.04` May be you have to give some time! But I'll be very happy to get it! :)

Comment: As I said I will try. with out trying I can not say I cant. @SauravKumar . I will let you know.

Comment: @rajagenupula: Thanks in advance :) Actually I tried but couldn't reach to the solution. When I saw this post, I got the person who could help me.. ;)

Comment: @SauravKumar as India GMT its dinner time :P , Now if you will excuse me I will do that. :P :P brb

Comment: @rajagenupula: ha ha ha! :P I am not telling you to find the solution and tell me now! ;) and I can't stop you to take your dinner!! But I suggest you to finish it around 6 to 7 PM.

Comment: @SauravKumar sorry for the delay , to get that feature you need to install nautilus 3.6 in your Ubuntu.

Comment: @rajagenupula: I searched a lot finally knew that yes it was `Nautilus 3.6` but I really don't know how to install it in `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`? I asked a question also,if you know I request you to post your answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/344370/is-there-any-way-to-install-latest-nautilus-file-manager-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Best Ubuntu File Managers are

**1 Nautilus**

This is default in Ubuntu-desktop but other flavors of Ubuntu  can get it with

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

The default file manager in GNOME DE too, Nautilus has an intuitive interface and offers features like previews, sorting, three view modes (icons, list, compact), bookmarks. Nautilus can be expanded via plugins and it also supports context menus.

**2 Dolphin**

This is default in Kubuntu-desktop but other flavors of Ubuntu  can get it with

```
sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

Dolphin is the default file manager for KDE focusing on usability. The main features of Dolphin are:

- Navigation bar for URLs, which allows to navigate quickly through the file hierarchy
- View properties are remembered for each folder
- Split of views and tabs are supported
- Network transparency
- File content previews
- Support for version control system plugins
- Integrated terminal
- Searching for file content and meta information

**3 thunar**

This is default in Xubuntu-desktop but other flavors of Ubuntu  can get it with

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

**4 Nemo**

we can install it with

```
 sudo apt-get install nemo
```

**5 [Double Commander ( new )](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/09/double-commander-dual-panel-file.html)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexx2000/doublecmd
sudo apt-get update
```

For **gtk** version

```
 sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk
```

for **Qt** version

```
sudo apt-get install doublecmd-qt
```

**6 Pcmanfm**

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

**7 Konqueror**

[Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/) is one of the most advanced file managers for KDE. Thanks to the underlying KDE technologies it can transparently access FTP and SFTP servers, zip files (and other archives), smb (Windows) shares, and even browse and rip audio CDs.

```
sudo apt-get install konqueror
```

Update:

[OMG! we have so many more! Click here for 20 File managers for Ubuntu](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/)

Comment: Could you add more details, the pros/cons of each of them? Maybe a short description?

Comment: @Braiam people are already trying to close this . I just want to help. OK any way I have lately found that bottom link . Thats having everything.

Comment: ha ha ha its looking too much funny ...what media players are there is not too much broad question http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-players-are-there/342606#342606 and what DE are there http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available/342010#342010 is not too much broad question but what file managers are there is a too broad question. GREAT!! nice job. keep going.

Comment: Everything I am doing here , just to help.Help people help you. Do what ever you want.

Comment: Did you noticed the "big" announce in the start of the question? Is maintaned for "historical" reasons, but that kind of questions are no accepted nor encouraged here (if you go to MSO, there are more of this kind). If you could narrowing down to something like, "what's the difference between each file manager installed by default in the different flavors of Ubuntu" or "how can I install several file managers without conflicts in Ubuntu" or several questions in the light of "How can I replace X file manager included by default with Z" would be more easy to maintain and search.

Comment: @Braiam first of all , i will agree with you . But is that Question become like that in one day ? NO NO its a collection from years . users like us did posted what they know to help others. Hope I am not wrong.

Comment: Check my edit on the question, I believe that way nobody will have complains with the question nor answers.

Comment: @Braiam Thank you my friend. Now its looking nice. i will try to update this to what Best i can.

Comment: Nautilus is super basic. It doesn't deserve to be #1 as the "best" file manager for Ubuntu. [Double Commander](http://askubuntu.com/questions/605076/what-is-an-ubuntu-file-manager-that-remembers-what-directories-were-open/807845#807845), Dolphin, [SpaceFM](http://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/spacefm-manual-next-en.html#introduction-highlights) - maybe.

Comment: Whoever rejected my edits to bring this answer up to date, you're a rule nazi. Please read [Focus on Improvements, Not Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:You_Can%27t_Follow_All_The_Rules,_All_The_Time): "If the change makes the article better in some way and worse in some other way, editors should comment on which one of these options is more important for themselves or others, not how the change fits this or that rule – because it's impossible to comply with all of them at once."