# What would be the alternatives for thunar file explorer?

Tags: filemanager

I'm looking for something basic to just browse my movie and tv show files etc.

So i need something light and simple.

Im pretty new to Linux so something that is pretty easy to get around with. As stated below my machine is pretty limited.

I'm using a limited machine. IBM Thinkpad T43 with Intel 2ghz processor and 2gb of Ram

Oh im using Xubuntu by the way

Comment: I am afraid only you can answer that question. All file browsers have their own set of properties which you might like / need or not.

Comment: Can you say exactly what you excpect from a file manager, or how the perfect file manager would be? As it is, this is not a good question because answers would depend on personal oppinions. Is should be a question for which one best answer could exist to fit this place.

Comment: thanks for all the responses. im pretty new to linux ill try all the different ones out and see what fits my fancy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What file managers are avilable for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343859/what-file-managers-are-avilable-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to try Marlin.

Marlin is a lightweight file browser built from the ground-up to be responsive easy to use, based on gtk3 and uses Gnome 3 technologies extensively.

Some key features of XFCE file-browser Thunar too are included to give it a certain slickness despite it being a File browser. Marlin uses 'extended actions' to manage files.

Features:

```
Tabbed browsing
Multiple-views
Single-click to open (default)
Configurable toolbars and interface
Plugin framework
Networking support (SSH, FTP, Windows share, HTTP and HTTPS)
Single click/double click to open file
```

To install it:

Open a terminal an run it:

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
apt-get update
apt-get install marlin
```

And enjoy it.

Comment: Also I like how you can colour coat the text background for each folder to make them stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [gentoo](http://gentoo.sourceforge.net/)

> gentoo is a graphical filemanager for Unix-like operating systems. It
>   is written completely in C, using the GTK+ toolkit for its user
>   interface. All file system access is done through the GIO library.
>   It's quite fast, and configured graphically.<sup>[gentoo](http://gentoo.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

You can also take a look at [Nemo](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=198).  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

<sup>[webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html)</sup>

Comment: I got Nemo up and running it seems pretty smooth. seems alot more fluid than Thunar. Thank you.

Comment: Also to remove Thunar do i just type in "sudo apt remove thunar" to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

[PCManFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMan_File_Manager) ([pcmanfm [image: Install pcmanfm]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pcmanfm)) is a very good and light file manager.

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus is great but it uses more system resources than Thunar. If you go with nautilus, I suggest running the following command in 14.04 after installation to enable a better recursive search function:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search false
```

To disable recursive search, just type the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-interactive-search true
```

Nemo is also an option.