# What is an Ubuntu file manager that remembers what directories were open?

Tags: filemanager

On windows I use xplorer2, which is a great dual-pane, multi-tab, file manager that, when you open it, opens with the same tabs and panes open as when you closed it, at the same directories.

I am looking for a file manager for Ubuntu that does that, or can be configured to do that, but so far cannot find one. However I'm pretty sure I remember having been able to configure a linux file manager to do that in the past.

I have tried Nautilus, Nemo, PCmanFM and mc, with no luck.

Does anybody know of a linux file manager that can do that - preferably with multi-tab and bookmarking capability?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **SpaceFM**.

```
sudo apt-get install spacefm
```

It automatically remembers your last directories by default and can have up to 4 panels at a time.

[image]

See here for more description of features:
[Linuxpoison blog](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2012/04/all-in-one-multi-panel-tabbed-file.html)

Comment: THank you Muzaffar. That looks like the sort of thing I was after.

Answer (score 0):

[Double Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Commander) is a [cross-platform](https://sourceforge.net/p/doublecmd/wiki/Download/) dual-pane file manager inspired by Total Commander, and each pane can accommodate an unlimited number of tabs.

[image: Double Commander 0.7.2 GTK on Ubuntu]