# Musicmatch Jukebox alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am wondering if there is a music program similar to the old Musicmatch Jukebox that was available when Windows XP first came out.

I already have my music saved as mp3. I want to be able to:

1. Play my music from a play list I create from my master list
2. Add to that list while my music is playing
3. Move songs around in that play list
4. Be able to save that play list.
5. Be able to copy the play list to my portable device or burn a CD of the playlist.

Is there any application available that can do that?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-music-and-video-players-are-there

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`amarok`](http://amarok.kde.org/) it allows also to listen streaming radio, it downloads lyrics of what you play, you can create your playlists...

... on the other side even [`vlc`](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can be used to play your music, listen streaming (or even to *see* streaming) almost in the same way, with a lot of radio station too, search for *Icecast radio directory* in the internet section of the sources...

If you think you can see [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-VLC-Media-Player-to-Listen-to-Internet-Radio)  about vlc.

Install via software center of with:

```
sudo apt-get install amarok  
sudo apt-get install vlc
```