# What program to install for DVD viewing on Ubuntu

Tags: dvd

What programs is best for viewing DVDs on Ubuntu?

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion if you do not give is anything to go on. Besides that: you have several options and all of them are free to try out so you can see for yourself if you spend a little time on getting to know them. Native totem (will also install drivers), vlc, (s)m-player to name 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What media (music and video) players are there?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-music-and-video-players-are-there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend for VLC Media Player or Totem Media Player.

Please check it out for further analysis:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu