# Are there any "pretty" video players for Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, mp4

14.04, specifically. Sorry if this is kind of a silly question. I have a lot of movies on mp4, and I was just curious if there is a video player that looks nice with which I can play them; VLC and the default player *work,* but they look somewhat ugly. I'm just curious if there is something that looks prettier, or matches Ubuntu more. Or perhaps a way to install themes/skins on VLC and the default player? Again, excuse the somewhat silly/trivial question. Thanks for any recommendations though!

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php

Comment: Check also [What media (music and video) players are there?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-music-and-video-players-are-there/199#199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skin VLC.

Here's a link for skins: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php

The skins go in  ~/.local/share/vlc/skins2 .

Hope this helps!