# What media players are available?

Tags: vlc, video-player, media

I'm trying to sync a subtitle in VLC but it doesn't work.

Syncing is working in Kodi but I don't like that player.

I don't want to install a lot of media players and test them.

Comment: @ChanganAuto software recommendations are on-topic. However this question could be improved if OP would be more clear about the features they want. The question could also benefit if OP would share their research so far. Searching for "media player Ubuntu" should produce lots of results on any popular search engine.

Comment: The only other big one is smplayer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What media (music and video) players are there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42532/what-media-music-and-video-players-are-there)